# How to have infinite tick?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a D3 force-graph that has functionality on `tick`. I've noticed that once the graph hits a standstill, the functionality will be lost until it is moved again. I am wondering how to prevent this or how to have `tick` always on?

An example is I have the following code

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  node.style("fill", function(d) { if (d.selected===true) {return "yellow"} else return d.data['color'] }).select("circle").style("stroke", "black");
});

// highlight node on dblclick
function highlight(d) {
  if (d.selected == false) {
    d.selected = true;
  }
  else {
    d.selected = false;
  }
}
```

It is constantly checking the node's data whether the `selected` (from the JSON) attribute is true or false. If it is true then it turns the node yellow. I've noticed that once the graph is still, and you double click, it will not turn the node yellow until you move the graph around again.

Comment: i cant comment so sorry that this is in the answers. Have you tried calling force.start() when the tick has finished ? Or after a certain amount of time ?

Comment: Based on the information you provided I don't think it will be a good idea to have the force run indefinitely (which you could by controlling factor `alpha`, btw). Why don't you move the call to `node.style("fill", ...)` to your double click handler function? That way, the animation could stop with the handler's functionality still in place.

Comment: I am not sure why I did not think about this in the first place. Thanks. I added the `node.style...`  fills to the `highlight()` function and I think it looks like this has the functionality of what I need done. I cannot remember my thought process for needing to put it in the tick so this works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tick` event is generated by the force layout when its internal status changes, i.e. when the nodes have moved. At some point, the force simulation will reach an equilibrium point where all the forces effecting the nodes are balanced and you won't see any further movement. At this point, no more `tick` events will be generated.

There are ways to "stretch out" the time required to reach an equilibrium, but you can't delay this indefinitely unless you disturb the nodes to unbalance the forces.

A better solution here (as pointed out in the comments) is to separate the functionality for updating the visualization to display the state of the force layout and the functionality for interacting with the nodes. In your case, you simply need run the code that highlights the node that was clicked on in the click handler.

Comment: Is there a way to give more than one function to a click handler? An example is if you have `.on("click", ...)` and another `.on("click", ...)` the second one will override the first one.

Comment: Yes, simply call both functions: `.on("click", function() { a(); b(); })`.